# Nautilus opens wrong directory

Tags: nautilus, bug-reporting

When I click on an item on nautilus places and devices menu, sometimes it opens another place as if I clicked on another item. For example, sometimes I click on "Home", but it opens "Desktop". Even sometimes it opens Trash when I click on Home. How to solve that?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your nautilus ?? I'm aware this bug is already fixed

Comment: @Liso I always install updates. It should be  up-to-date